# Counting true/false in complex data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to do something rather complex in R, and I am not really sure where to start.

I have a dataframe that looks sort of like this:

```
main_val sub_val bit_one bit_two
 one      a        1       1
 one      a        1       0
 one      a        1       1
 one      b        1       0
 two      a        1       1
 two      b        1       1
 two      a        1       1
```

Now I to count the number of 0s, 1s, 2s, and 3s represented by the bits for each sub value of each main value. So this should return:

```
main_val sub_val  0s  1s  2s  3s
 one       a      0   0   1   2
 one       b      0   0   1   0
 two       a      0   0   0   2
 two       b      0   0   0   1
```

Any thought on how to do this? I can only think of ugly for loops that would take forever (this will be run on ALOT of data).

Comment: I believe you want the aggregate function. I will write an answer with an example for you.

Comment: It's a two-bit binary number, @DavidArenburg - if I am reading the question right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pardon my earlier comment - I think you actually just need `table()` and `reshape()` to do this in base R. It may get slow if you have a truly huge amount of data, however, at which point I suggest investigating `data.table`.

```
# Start by turning of stringsAsFactors
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create fake data
fake.data <- data.frame(main_val = c("one","one","one","one","two","two","two"),
                        sub_val = c("a","a","a","b","a","b","a"),
                        bit_one = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        bit_two = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1))

# Generate a decimal representation of your two bits
fake.data$decimal <- fake.data$bit_one*1 +fake.data$bit_two*2

# Create a table of the results, then reshape it
fake.data.summary <- as.data.frame(table(Main=fake.data$main_val,
                                         Sub=fake.data$sub_val,
                                         Value=fake.data$decimal))

fake.data.summary <- reshape(data = fake.data.summary,
                             v.names = "Freq",
                             idvar = c("Main","Sub"),
                             timevar = "Value",
                             direction = "wide")
```

Note that in this example, you will get only one and three in the output, since only one and three are in the input. If uniform outputs are desired despite what may or may not be present, you may need to do some sanitization of the output - but I suspect you don't need that, as you will likely have enough volume to ensure that 0 through 3 are represented.

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I was needing!

Comment: Hey, what if I wanted to add another variable, call it main_companion, that is in 1 to 1 correspondence with the main_val. For example, main could be 'one', 'two' 'three'... and main_comp would be 1, 2, 3. How would I get these to stay in the reshaped data? I tried adding it as a new variable to idvar, timevar, and varying and it crashes each time.

Comment: Generally, if you have another question, it's good to actually ask it again in case I'm not able answer promptly. That way, you can also add the error messages, minimal working example, and other things.

Answer (score 3):

As @TARehman already mentioned in his answer, for huge datasets you might want to use `data.table`. So, therefore a `data.table` alternative of the answer of @TARehman:

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- dcast(setDT(df)[, .("dec" = paste0("d",(bit_one*1 + bit_two*2))), by = .(main_val,sub_val)
                       ][, .N, by = .(main_val,sub_val,dec)], 
             main_val + sub_val ~ dec, value.var = "N", fill = 0)
```

this gives:

```
> df2
   main_val sub_val d1 d3
1:      one       a  1  2
2:      one       b  1  0
3:      two       a  0  2
4:      two       b  0  1
```

Comment: I think you need to encode the numbers he gave into binary (0 to 3, represented in two bits).

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is now giving the same output as the other answer.